# Play Framework Asset Pipeline

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm currently migrating my app from Grails do Play Framework. I've previously worked with Ruby on Rails and Grails, didn't like both the frameworks but i loved one thing, their Sprockets Asset Pipeline.

Is there any way to get this [Pipeline](https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline) to work on Play Framework?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about RoR but maybe you are looking for webjars?

Comment: I only want to include 1 Minified and Fingerprinted javascript file on each page, that's what this does

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web is what you want.

Comment: @marcospereira, post that in an Answer so i can give you Thumbs up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web is what you want.

See also the play docs:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Assets